# How to compute the capacity of a quantum channel from its Kraus operators?

Tags: quantum-operation, kraus-representation, channel-capacity

Is there a working rule to compute the capacity of a quantum channel described by a set of Kraus operators $\{K_i\}$?

Comment: Not a nice one no. The best result is the LSD theorem which says that the quantum channel capacity is the regularization of the coherent information, which means it involves a limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and so finding the capacity is generally an unbounded optimization problem. However if your Kraus operators satisfy certain conditions then it can be easier, for instance if the channel is degradable.

Comment: Thanks, @Connor. Similar question: How to check "degradability" knowing the  Kraus operators?

Comment: It would be sufficient to show that $ker(T)\subseteq ket(T^C)$ where $T$ is your channel and $T^C$ is its complementary channel, both of which do have have nice formulas in terms of the Kraus operators for $T$. Though I am not sure how you could get a handle on characterizing the operators in the kernel of $T$... this (older) paper is a good starting point https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.1360.pdf not sure what is state of the art these days though.